# how to view event "my schedule" at calendar in servicenow

Tags: events, calendar, servicenow

we have created a new events,now we have to know how to see those events in calendar.Using the below API,we can fetch it by API.

```
https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmn_schedule_span/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

but in calendar,no events are displayed.

[image]

Please help us to see the created events in calendar ("MY SCHEDULE")

Comment: Please provide example of the created events. Are they even tied to a user? (admin, in your case)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a different calendar. To see all schedules -> https://myinstance/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fcmn_schedule_list.do

Open a schedule and click on Show Schedule and it will open the calendar showing the schedule. Please check screenshots.
[image]

Comment: Thanks!!yes i have checked this too...In some account it showing the marked events,but some accounts doesn't have the events which is marked